# What qualifies as a small business in the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, investment-property

I am a Canadian citizen living in the United States (in California) and would like to buy an investment property. I want to declare a small business for owning and managing the property *which I anticipate would come with tax deductions* (i.e. on the interest payments of the mortgage and deductions for my business office for running the property business). A key point is that I am considering buying an investment property in Canada.

Would my business be legitimate and recognized by the IRS? What are the requirements for a small business to be recognized? Where can I find definitive answers about these things?

Please let me know if any of my assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, this is a good resource: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed

Comment: You should consider the tax consequences when you sell the property or if you pass away while owning it too. Cross-border property ownership can be [complex](https://skltax.com/real-estate-ownership-u-s-citizens-canada/).